# Can't get iFrame to work in Internet Explorer on my redesign

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, html

I'm in the process of doing some minor redesign on my site, and I'm struggling with using an iFrame to display a google map. The iFrame is showing in Chrome with no issue, but it isn't in IE9. Interestingly, I can see it start to load (and sometimes even see the "Map/Sat/Terrain" options show up that you get when it loads properly, but then the frame goes blank. I haven't changed the code for creating the map, and it works fine on my production version of the site in both Chrome and IE. It must be something with the new DIVs I'm using, but I just can't seem to find it. To see it in context, here are the two sites:
Production: http://www.findthefishing.com/guidepage.php?guideID=42
Redesign: http://www.findthefishing.com/guidepage2.php?guideID=42

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

```
<div id="guidepagecontent">
<div id="guidepagemapcont">
<div id="guidepagemap">
<iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=4000+Crandon+Blvd,+Key+Biscayne,+FL&hl=en&z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=4000+Crandon+Blvd,+Key+Biscayne,+FL&hl=en&z=14" target="_blank"> View Larger Map</a></div>
</div>


#guidepagemapcont {
float: right;
width: 310px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
}

#guidepagemap {
background-color: #ffffff;
padding:0px 0px 10px 10px; 
font-size: 14px;
text-align:center;
}

#guidepagecontent {
padding: 10px;
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #ffffff;
position: relative;
}
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone can give me some insight!

Comment: You opened three `DIV`s and just closed two `DIV`s? Is that a typo?

Comment: If you look at the HTML in the page, they've just copied one too many DIVs - it does close properly in context. OP: Both versions are loading fine for me in IE9.

Comment: @Passerby - yes, it was a typo - I just didn't copy enough of the code over.

Comment: @zenkaty - it looks like it was working fine for you before I put in the "fix." Perhaps it was working fine the whole time, but I was just having an intermittent issue with the IE-Google connection. Either way, the code should be more clean now, and everything appears to be working. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML on your new page has quite a few problems:

1. No doctype declared
2. Two HEAD sections declared - one in the CORRECT place and one within the BODY tag

Fixing these and any other HTML issues may resolve your problem.

Comment: Billy, thanks for the help. That worked. It started to work in IE8 (I haven't had a chance to check IE9) after I fixed the double HEAD tags, but before I declared the doctype. I had the same problems on my production version of the page, so I can't explain why it worked without those fixes, but I'm grateful it solved it either way. Thanks again!